# How to get `ip addr show` to only show links of a specific type

Tags: iproute

How does one get `ip addr show` to only show links of a specific type, without using a secondary process like grep to do filtering?

According to [man 8 ip-address](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-address.8.html), this should be possible using the following, but when I run these, I get no results:

```
ip addr show type "link/loopback"
ip addr show type "loopback"
```

Comment: According to the man page there is no type "loopback", you have to choose from the list of types: `TYPE := [ bridge | bridge_slave | bond | bond_slave | can | dummy |
               hsr | ifb | ipoib | macvlan | macvtap | vcan | veth | vlan |
               vxlan | ip6tnl | ipip | sit | gre | gretap | erspan | ip6gre
               | ip6gretap | ip6erspan | vti | vrf | nlmon | ipvlan | lowpan
               | geneve | macsec ]`

Comment: So there is no way to filter on `loopback` or `ether`. That's disappointing.

Comment: It appears so, yes. But I'm not the most linux experienced user so there may be something else I'm not aware of.

Comment: You can use the fact that loopback is usually named `lo` and filter on IFNAME instead, so `ip addr show lo` will work. Not sure if it is relevant for your use though.

Comment: @Fiisch I think OP wants to filter `link/ether`, `link/loopback`, etc. lines, instead of filtering an interface.

Comment: the command ip addr show - Is a searching function for devices - from what I can see in the options there's no filtering functions. Is there a reason you don't wish to use a program to filter this?

Comment: >Is there a reason you don't wish to use a program to filter this?

Running this from an initrd, so I want to avoid adding additional binaries to it to keep the size down.

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple:

```
hostname -i
```

Usually, I'm not looking for loopback but the ip so

```
hostname -I
```

And if you want both while reducing the textual noise and adding color

```
ip addr | grep inet
```

Comment: You basically gave him exactly what he said he wasn't looking for.

Comment: @deltaray I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing this in Python.  I haven't tried translating this using grep.

```
import re
import shlex
import subprocess

""" Return a list of interface name strings """

RE_PATT = "^\d+: (\w+).+\n +link/loopback"
proc = subprocess.run(
    shlex.split("ip link show"),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
interface_list = re.findall(RE_PATT, proc.stdout, re.MULTILINE)
```